# EF DataContext, set schema name programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql, ef-postgresql

I am currently using EF DataContext with class like this :

```
[Table(Name = "schema.tablename")]    
public class Table
{
  [Column(Name = "id", DbType = "serial", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false)]
  public int ID { get; set; }    

  ...
}
```

Is there a way how to assign schema name dynamically from web.config?
I tried this

```
   public Table<Table> tables { get { return GetTable<Table("schema"); } }
```

but this method is obsolete and it doesn't work. 
My database is potgresql, I am using Npgsql for connection, EF version is 6.0

Answer (score 1):

In your `DbContext` implementation:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema( "schema" );
}
```

Comment: DataContext - not DbContext. I had some troubles with DbContext so I ended up with DataContext. And it's working good so far, except of this